# getting all posts the user has liked from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get all the posts the user has liked displaying and not all posts.

I have database tables as follows:

**likes (columns (int): likeID, likeBy, likeOn)**

**posts (columns: postID, postBy, text, likeCount)**

**users (Columns: userID, username)**

Here is my code to get the users liked post (at the moment it gets all liked posts on database and not user liked posts)

```
public function likes($user_id, $num){

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `likes`, `posts`, `users` WHERE `likeOn` = `userID` and `user_id` = `postBy` ORDER BY `likeOn` DESC");

    $stmt->bindParam(":num", $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tweets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

any ideas on how to get the posts liked by the user and not all liked posts?

Comment: `likes.likeOn`, `users.userID`, etc etc. MySQL doesn't know which columns from which table you're referencing. Specify the table name and then the column like in my two examples.

Comment: You also appear to have forgotten to JOIN the tables

Comment: @Loek I am new to php can you give an example in code please

Comment: With your current table setup it isn't possible. You need to add the liked post id to the likes table and save that with the like itself. (The most elegant way is to do this with an foreign key)

Comment: @MackyLasmu This has nothing to do with your PHP code. That is fine. It's your SQL query.

Comment: @Thom The likeOn is the postID

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in comments, your schema is not structured in a proper way to have solid relations between tables.

But, given your current structure (and assuming you are updating the likes count, and that posts.postBy contains the user id), you could try something like:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts AS p WHERE COUNT(p.likeCount) > 0 AND p.postBy = the_user_id_variable
```

If you need posts only, and the userId is contained inside the post row, you do not need to join different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

I changed your query so the statement will return the posts and likes coupled together with the inner join

```
public function likes($user_id, $num){

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * likes INNER JOIN posts ON likes.likeOn = posts.postID WHERE likes.likeBy = ? ORDER BY `likeOn` DESC");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":num", $num, PDO::PARAM_INT); // Don't know what this does 
    $stmt->execute();
    $tweets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

**Edit:** removed the User table from the query because the userid allready existed in the like table (likeBy).

Comment: I think OP is asking for posts, not users.

Comment: @AndreaGolin This statement will return the posts, likes and User (a bit overkill) from the given userID. This gives me the idea for a small improvement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.postID from posts p inner join likes l on l.likeOn=p.postID inner join users u on u.userID = l.likeBy;
```

I think the above query will work for you try it in MySQL database.